# Navigating a Web Page and Submitting Data

Tags: c#, web

I'm looking for some information on interacting with websites with C#. I would like to navigate threw pages and also submit data.

I'm not really sure what way to go about it, Also I'm not sure if C# is even the best choice as far as language.

Any thoughts ? Reference Materials ?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends a lot on what type of data you are talking about. There are different approaches to different types of data, and also if the data should be submitted by every page change or be stored for when the user reaches the last page and then submits.

Would you care to specify some more information regarding what exactly you are looking for by asking this question?

Comment: I guess the description would be similar to a bot or web crawler. I'm intending to use it on a dating site to harvest accounts and message them. There is many similar programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a web page using C# with something like this (stolen from [here](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/Content/HowToWriteAWebCrawlerInCSharp.aspx)):

```
    private static string GetWebText(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();

        return htmlText;
    }
```

Next, I'd use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and do whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

A good start to developing websites in asp.net (both c# and vb) is [Beginning asp.net 4 in c# & VB](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/about/aboutmybooks/beginningaspnet4) by [Imar Spaanjaars](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/).  He also has a lot of good material on his blog.

The [ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/) site from Microsoft is a good resource too and [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) is a good development platform.

In terms of learning c#, [Csharp-station](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx) has lots of tutorials and the [Yellow book](http://csharpcourse.com/) by Rob Miles is a good resource also.

UPDATE

In response to the last comment, [Screen Scraping](http://madskristensen.net/post/Screen-scraping-in-C.aspx) may be what you are looking for.